# Plotting time-series in R

Tags: r, plot, time-series

I would like to create some quality plots for my thesis. So the R-code is running and delivered estimation results running from 1960 Q1 to 2017 Q2. So the quarterly results are within a table, but without a column with dates. My question is, how do I plot this time series?

A 2nd related question. I also have a number of parameter estimates which I would like to present in an aesthetic looking table, compatible with latex.

Two screenshots are included to give a better understanding of the issue.

Best,
Sean

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0yj4.png)

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJq7g.png)

Comment: Don't post data as screenshots. You can use `dput` to post (part of) your sample data. [UPDATE] As this question has been flagged as a duplicate, for future posts you should review how to provide a [minimal reproducible example/attempt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), including sample data.

Comment: Please review this post to learn how to ask a question with reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Making screenshot is a bad way to share data.